# DHCP configuration for WAN

Tags: windows, cisco, dhcp, wide-area-network

I'm unsure exactly what I'm asking for here, which makes it difficult to search so please let me know if it has been answered before (I'm sure it has).

Current config is a DHCP server hosted in a data center. We have 8 sites connected to our WAN. All 8 sites get their DHCP leases from the DHCP server (W2k8r2) and are in separate dhcp scopes- 10.250.1.xx - 10.250.8.xx etc. 
We are in the process of moving away from the DataCenter and hosting it internally at our head office. I would like to keep the same topology, same scopes and same DHCP assignment process. My question is, how do I specify on the new DHCP server (W2012r2) what IPs are to be assigned to what scopes? We use various Cisco routers at all sites and I know we will need to update the IP_Helper to point to the new DHCP server but I'm unsure of how exactly each site will know which scope is to be used? Will I need to add ip_helper entries for all scopes on the router of our main office that houses the new DHCP server?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

Todd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows DHCP server will return an address based on the network that the client's DHCP request came from.

When you setup the scope, you set up the addresses that should be used via the Address Pool for that scope.  It is then very smart about returning an address for the network that the client is connected to.

Comment: So, if router 1 is configured as 10.10.1.1, it will automatically be assigned addresses from the 10.10.1.1 scope etc?

Comment: I made the change to test what RLines had mentioned and it works as expected. Thanks!